# mail() not working

Tags: php

I am struggling to send mails through PHP, running on IIS7.  I have an SMTP server running on the server which I can access through telnet and send a mail through with no problems, and php.ini is configured as follows:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

When I run a simple PHP script to test the mail function:

```
    $to = "test@email.com";
    $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
    $from = "someonelse@example.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
        echo('ok');
    }
    else
    {
        echo('not ok');
    }
```

ok is returned however no mail is received.  I have set `error_reporting(-1);` and am getting no errors or warnings either.  I'm stumped as to what could wrong?

Comment: watch your /var/log/mail or /var/log/mail.err

Comment: are you sending the email to a good email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the issue - it was the sendmail_from setting in php.ini.  Even though the script is not using this value it seems like it has to be a well formed email address however it wasn't.  Setting it to test@mail.com and restarting the site has done the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
```

You have to end your headers with line breaks like that.

Comment: actually you should use PHP_EOL instead of the "\r\n".

Comment: @jribeiro I'd actually never heard of that before.  Just did a little reading on it.  Thanks for the info.